# Как правильно собрать Boost из исходников?

Tags: c++, linux, github, cmake, boost

На моей системе последней версией Boost, которую выдаёт apt, является 1.65.1, мне же нужна 1.72.0, для чего я хочу поставить её из исходников. Мне нужна библиотека Asio, и ещё две библиотеки, от которых она зависит: System и Regex.

Я их склонировал в '/opt/.source/Boost/'. Теперь мне нужно их собрать. В склонированных репозиториях я заметил файл CMakeLists.txt, что как бы намекает, что их можно собрать CMake'ом, но в руководствах (далеко не новых) советуют использовать bjam (b2), который я так и не нашел для Linux.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне его лучше поставить, чтобы затем включить в свой проект на CMake.

Comment: А можете подсказать, откуда брали исходники `asio` с `CMakeLists` для него?

Comment: @mkkik, у Asio нет CMakeLists.txt, я говорил про System и Regex.

Comment: Мне просто интересно, что там такого есть, что нужно тянуть свежий-свежий буст. В большинстве случаев, это абсолютно не нужно. Но всегда можно установить генту, там уже 1.72 :) . В целом, обычно буст просто компилят отдельно (как здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu) а не включают в CMake на компиляцию.

Comment: @KoVadim, есть. В 1.72.0 кое-что уже deprecated, а в более ранних новые штуки, которые пришли на замену deprecated - не компилятся.

Comment: более чем уверен, что можно просто на чистых плюсах написать и все будет проще и красивше.

Comment: @kovadim, ну asio не завезли ещё даже в c++20, так что писать его вы запаритесь, даже если от туда нужно 1/10. К сожалению в стандартной либе нет ни чего для работы с сетью.

Comment: Мой опыт показал, что лучше использовать обвязку для curl или обычный сокет. Работает лучше и проще. Также неплохо справляется QT (если позволяют обстоятельства). Не знаю почему, но во всех проектах, которые я видел, если туда завезли буст, то можно забывать о проекте, он скоро накроется. Но это мое личное мнение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

```
cd /opt/.source
wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.72.0/source/boost_1_72_0.tar.gz
tar -xvzf boost_1_72_0.tar.gz

cd boost_1_72_0
./bootstrap.sh
mkdir /opt/Boost

./b2 \
--with-system \
--with-regex \
install --prefix=/opt/Boost
```

**PS:** В прошлый раз я где-то в сети случайно нашёл эту ссылку (`wget`) на репозиторий с архивами. Но тоже самое можно было сделать, склонировав **Boost** целиком с **GitHub** [отсюда](https://github.com/boostorg/boost). Под пользователем *boostorg* очень много репозиториев, поэтому новичкам можно легко запутаться. Также будет полезным заглянуть на официальный сайт [B2 (Boost.Build)](https://boostorg.github.io/build/). Эта система сборки специально создавалась для билда Boost'а.